# How to plot a line and set the color of every line in a nested list?

Tags: python, list, loops, matplotlib

I had a nested list and a function:

```
a = [[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[5,7]]

def triple(a):
    return (a**2)+3
```

I tried to plot every point in the sublist like the first value connected to second, the second connected to the third and stop at the last value in the sublist. `x` is the value in the sublist, `y` is `triple(y for y in sublist)`

```
for g in a:
    for t in g:
        plt.scatter(t, triple(t))
for g in a:
    for o in range(len(g)):
        plt.plot([g[o],g[o+1]], [triple(g[o]), triple(g[o+1])], color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

I tried this but it didn't get the desire output I wanted.

What should I do to plot every sublist in `a` and get three different colors of line?

Comment: Does this achieve what you want: `for sublist in a: plt.plot(sublist, [triple(s) for s in sublist], 'o-')` ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You specified `color='red'` so every your line is drawn with one color.
2. You use `plt.scatter` to draw circles. There is no need to do it, you can use `marker` parameter in `plt.plot`.
3. Your code is throwing a `ValueError` because when `o` is in the last element of `g`, `o+1` will point to the undefined element. I rewrote this line.

I changed `a` a bit, just for a more distinguished view. Here is the final code:

```
a = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
for g in a:
    plt.plot(g, [(x**2)+3 for x in g], marker='.')
plt.show()
```